# Amazon cloud suggestions on a set of data

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I have a cloud search domain which is integrated and working well to generate fields.

I have three facets which are

1. Class
2. Title
3. Content

all the above are text fields

Now i have a need to add suggestions and get search term suggestions on the site. for this i've got two requirements

1. To give suggestions from the Title as the source
2. To provide suggestions from the Title but also only with the entries which has Class as Event

I am can easily do the first one,

how do i do the second ?

any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no solution for this one,

what i did was to have two indexes, and get the suggestions from one. the indexes were

1. Class
2. Title
3. EventTitle
4. Content

and for one fields i got the suggesters by Title and for the other one got them from EventTitle.